# Ширина центрального блока

Tags: facebook, вконтакте

Подскажите, какова ширина центрального блока (без правого чата) facebook? Она фиксированная `1000px`? И какова ширина [vk.com](http://vk.com), она фиксированная `790px`?

Comment: Проинспектируй элемент в опере

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook:

```
.hasLeftCol #contentCol { 
    border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    margin-left: 181px;
    min-height: 600px;
    width:799px;
}
```

Vk: (без меню)

```
#page_body {
   width: 631px;
}
```

Ширина фиксированная в обоих случаях.

Comment: В контакте фиксированная,ширина центрального блока во всех случаях ровна 631 пиксель,а в фейсбуке что ?

Comment: Да, скорее всего в вк фиксированная, но меня смущает, что она задана не в стилях, а в атрибуте style.
В лицокниге она точно фиксированная, 799px. Филксированная ил нет - легко определить, отлепите браузер от полноэкранного режима и поизменяйте ширину. Если расстояния между картинками, ширина блоков не изменяется, то она как раз задана фиксированно.